# Passing JavaScript variable gives an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, jstl

I used to generate a field set when a button is clicked in my application. That field set inputs take attribute of an object. Whenever add button is clicked, I have to generate a field set. Spring bind used for input elements.

I set this newly created object in a list. So, when I'm generating the field set, I have to name it properly which set the object to next element. I tried this and it's not working.

```
path="subdivisondto.subDevisions[${'+parseInt(countnum)+'}].subDivisonName">
```

This code comes inside jQuery `append` method.

I tried with `parseInt(countnum)`. But, it's not working.

```
subDevisions
```

is a list. So, I have to increase the one by one using a variable to set the object to list.

Comment: what do you get when doing `alert("${'+parseInt(countnum)+'}")`

Comment: it gives the integer value 1. I don't know why it's not passed. This code is inside jquery append function. I have passed this binding parnt and input elements as string to append(). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Who processes the `${}`? If the code above is in JavaScript, how is Spring involved? What element uses the attribute `path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering what `${'+parseInt(countnum)+'}` is supposed to achieve. Let's assume that `parseInt(countnum)` converts the string `countnum` to an integer. So this would give (for example): `${'+1+'}`

That looks like you convert a string to an integer just to get a new string. How about this:

```
<%
String path = "subdivisondto.subDevisions[" + countnum + ".subDivisonName";
%>
<... path="<%= path %>">
```